# Can I delete flashlogs.txt?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

As a ActionScript3 developer I must use debugging tools to trace output to the console. I stumbled across a file that is used with debugging called flashlogs.txt. Can I delete this file? It is located in the users/user/library/preferences/macromedia/flashplayer/logs/ directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, next time FlashRuntime will create it again if you have `ErrorReportingEnable=1` in your `mm.cfg`.

You can also change file location and change mode for log write `PolicyFileLogAppend = 0|1`.

For more info check out that doc http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fc9.html